# NonCommutativeMultiply syntax question

Tags: function-construction, syntax, algebra

I define:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[left___, HoldPattern[Times[u[x_], p : (a[k_] | SuperDagger[a][k_])]], 
right___] := u[x] NonCommutativeMultiply[left, p, right]
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

since I want the function `u[x_]` to commute with `a[k_], SuperDagger[a][k_]`

Now if i try

```
In:= a[k] ** u[k]*a[q]
Out= a[q] a[k] ** u[k]    (*  which is not the desired output*)
```

if i try

```
In:= a[k] ** (u[k] a[q])
Out= a[k] ** a[q] u[k]
```

which is better but still it's not `u[k] a[k] ** a[q]`

I can't figure out why my definition isn't working. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that ** distributes over *. That means: a[k] ** u[k]*a[q] is interpreted as:   (a[k] ** u[k]) * ( a[k] **a[q]). If you write: a[k] ** (u[k]*a[q]) you get: a[k] ** a[q] u[k]

Comment: @DanielHuber I thought my rule would take care of that? Even with `a[k] ** (u[k] a[q])` the output places `u[k]`  after `a[k] ** a[q] ` not before. How should I change it to have the desired output?

Comment: "Times" has the attribute "Orderless". Therefore MMA will rearrange the expression according to its own rules (I think, lexicographically, but I am not sure)

Comment: @DanielHuber Geez,  you are right. Even if I add `orderless` to `NonCommutativeMultiply` nothing changes.The order is decided by `Sort`  which orders symbols by their names, and in the event of a tie, by their contexts. Please post your comments as an answer. They are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `NonCommutativeMultiply` (`**`) distributes over `Times`.

That means: `a[k] ** u[k]*a[q]` is interpreted as: `(a[k] ** u[k]) * (a[k] ** a[q])`. If you write: `a[k] ** (u[k]*a[q])` you get: `a[k] ** a[q] u[k]`

Furthermore, `Times` has the attribute `Orderless`.  Therefore MMA will rearrange the expression according to its own rules (I think lexicographically, but I am not sure).